# link_to, use data for popup, without confirm options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can it be done without confirm dialog/confirm options - just regular info window.

I'am trying with this...

```
<%= link_to "Info", customer, remote:true, data: 
{confirm: "Customer Info: #{customer.first_name}"} %>
```

This shows me choose options, I just want OK button.

I have datatable with a lot of columns. In one column (Customer ID), I have info button. On that click, i just wan to show additional data. No network call, I have all data in datatable array. Just wan to call it with link to using data, but without confirm options (Cancel/Ok), just regular Ok button. Without making other custom dialog and sending data there. Thanks.

Comment: question is not clear, can you elaborate it little more?

Comment: @Gabbar I have datatable with a lot of columns. In one column (Customer ID), I have info button. On that click, i just wan to show additional data. No network call, I have all data in datatable array. Just wan to call it with link to using data, but without confirm options (Cancel/Ok), just regular Ok button. Without making other custom dialog and sending data there. Thanks.

Comment: so far as i understand you don't want  to use `link_to` am i right?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: @Gabbar Everything is ok, I just dont't want to have button options (Cancel/Ok). I want to use link_to with data {:confirm} to act like Info dialog, not confirm dialog.

Comment: are your getting all value in same html that you want to show ?

Comment: @Gabbar <tr id="customer_<%= customer.id %>">
  <td><%= customer.first_name %></td>
  <td><%= customer.last_name %></td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', customer, remote: true, data: {confirm: "Delete Customer: #{customer.first_name} #{customer.last_name}"}, :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-danger' %>

Just want to use this (delete) to act as a info detail (no Cancel/Ok options, just OK)... Hot to remove Cancel opotion from "data: {confirm:" ? Maybe, some :popup attribute or something like that?

Comment: lets try the given solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr id="customer_<%= customer.id %>">
  <td><%= customer.first_name %></td>
  <td><%= customer.last_name %></td>
  <td> <%= link_to 'Delete','', :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-danger', :onclick => 'show_info('<%=customer.first_name%>', '<%=customer.last_name%>');' %></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_info(first_name, last_name){
    var text = first_name + ' ' + last_name
    alert(text);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Thank you. I just did it this way:

          <td>
          <div class="ui button" data-tooltip="<%= customer["first_name"]%>" data-position="top left"> Top Left
          </td>

Semantic.

Comment: @jack yep, its alright, this can be done in many ways but by using script block in future you can cal ajax request also incase you needed to hit server on any action, on click that button, anyway feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it helped you :)